# docker-compose not working on Debian 8.2

Tags: debian, docker-compose

I'm currently testing docker on a Debian 8.2 server and I'm seeking help from mor experienced people.

I've followed the official documentation to install docker (http://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/) and I'm now trying docker compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
I've installed compose using pip as described here on the official documentation ("pip install -U docker-compose")

Running "docker-compose" gives me the help screen, but "docker-compose up" doesn't work and gives me a lot of errors.

Any idea on how I can make this to work?
Am I missing something? A pre-requisite maybe?

```
root@server:~/dockerfiles/compose-test# docker-compose up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 39, in main
    command.sys_dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 21, in sys_dispatch
    self.dispatch(sys.argv[1:], None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 27, in dispatch
    super(Command, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 24, in dispatch
    self.perform_command(*self.parse(argv, global_options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 57, in perform_command
    verbose=options.get('--verbose'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 73, in get_project
    config_details = config.find(self.base_dir, config_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config.py", line 107, in find
    return ConfigDetails(load_yaml(filename), os.path.dirname(filename), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config.py", line 558, in load_yaml
    return yaml.safe_load(fh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 93, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 580, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 8
root@server:~/dockerfiles/compose-test#
```

I'm running docker 1.8.2 and compose 1.4.2

Comment: It looks like your `docker-compose.yml` has some invalid syntax . The error message says it's at line 3 colume 8.

Comment: Hi @dnephin, thanks for pointing that out to me, you are right!
My docker-compose.yml had a small indentation mistake. I've been able to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing docker compose using curl works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.4.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: The new url for the latest version is:
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

I have manually pulled the images instead of pulling them while running `docker-compose.yml`. When I ran `docker-compose.yml` it worked.